# How to create a borderless canvas for animate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, animate

I have an example:

```tex
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[
    autoplay,
    autopause,
    nomouse,
    loop
]{animate}

\begin{document}

The first animation.

\begin{animateinline}[
        begin={
                \begin{tikzpicture}[black, scale = 1,line width = 1pt]
                    \useasboundingbox[draw, line width = 0] (0, 0) rectangle(4, 4);
                       },
                    end={\end{tikzpicture}}
    ]{4}
    \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(1,1);
    \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(2,2);
    \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(3,3);
    \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(4,4);
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I know the purpose of `\useasboundingbox[draw, line width = 0] (0, 0) rectangle(4, 4);` is equivalent to defining the size of the canvas.

I want it to be borderless. I tried to set `line width = 0`but that didn't have the desired effect.

How can I remove its border.

Comment: `draw=none` in `useasboundingbox`, or just `\useasboundingbox (0, 0) rectangle(4, 4);`

Comment: And even this will work too
`\useasboundingbox[line width = 3] (0, 0) rectangle(4, 4);`

Comment: @kabenyuk But for which purpose should option `line width = 3` be added?

Answer (score 1):

Following the previous question: [How to use tikz and animate to animate in article document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639382/how-to-use-tikz-and-animate-to-animate-in-article-document-class), and applying the comments to a MWE, we have:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[
autoplay,
autopause,
nomouse,
loop
]{animate}

\begin{document}
The first animation.

\begin{animateinline}[
  begin={
    \begin{tikzpicture}[black, scale = 1, draw=none]
      \useasboundingbox (0, 0) rectangle(4, 4);
    },
    end={\end{tikzpicture}}
  ]{4}
  \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(1,1);
  \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(2,2);
  \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(3,3);
  \newframe \draw[->](0,0)--(4,4);
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image].